# undefined environment variables in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

I am new to React and I want to use Evironment Variables in my App. I tried out many solutions from the web but nothing worked out so here is my configuration:
i created a `process.env` file in my root directory and inside this file I initialized my variables like this:

```
REACT_APP_SERVICE_ID=key
REACT_APP_TEMPLATE_ID=key_2
REACT_APP_API_KEY=key_3
```

after I called them in my component like so:

```
const serviceId = process.env.REACT_APP_SERVICE_ID;
const templateId = process.env.REACT_APP_TEMPLATE_ID;
const public_key = process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY;
```

but when i log them, the console shows `undefined`. I also tried out using `dotenv-webpack` , even that doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rename the filename from `process.env` to `.env`